# How to deactivate Ease of Access in window in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, accessibility

By mistake I had activated  ease of access "use comp. w/o mouse or keyboard" & from that my laptop keyboard is not giving any response i.e. not working so I have  to  use online keyboard & it is uncomfortable to use. So how can I activate my keyboard  again ? I knew cntrl pnl-ease of acces- but I couldn't able to found deactivate option.

Comment: Are you saying that you turned on the online keyboard but that it's not responding, or that because you turned on the online keyboard your normal keyboard is not responding?

Comment: Hmmm.. so you are having access trouble with ease of access.

Comment: My normal laptop keyboard is not wok'g. I'm now us'g online;but not comfortable to use

Comment: Where did you find “use computer without mouse or keyboard”? That is not part of the Ease of Access applet (or Windows for that matter). Is it a laptop-specific feature? Did you ever fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the control panel there is the Ease Of Access center. There you should be able to disable any enabled features.